# "Decline" text box automatically focuses and breaks tab-navigation

Tags: bug, user-interface, moderator-tools, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

Normally the forms used on Stack Exchange are quite handy to be used with keyboard navigation, since they respect tab order and the buttons can be activated, for example, with <kbd>Space</kbd>.

When you enter text in the "other" field for decline messages, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the *decline* button, the focus is automatically put back on the "other" field.

> [image]

The same happens when you try to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> back to one of the predefined reasons. It is therefore impossible to use this form with the keyboard.

Please remove the event handler that is causing this – there is no obvious reason for forcing the user to stay in the input field.

<sub>It'd also be nice to have the `focus` lay on one of the elements already, so that I can start tabbing through the form right away.</sub>